# Java JFrame: Windows Layout & Embed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

[image: design layout]
I need to define a layout for a Jframe Window, as in the picture above.

Below is my approach.
[image: my approach]
A Picture from my resources folder (/resources/...jpg) embed inside the middle(main).
Top, Bottom, Left and Right divided in four parts, whereas their content is a labeled button stretched, so I can map some methods on it later, that change the picture inside the main container.

I tried to display the picture, but I get the result you see in my screenshot. I can't see it inside my main container and I receive no error message.

I don't know if this is because of my wrong approach of using JFrame.
Below you can see my code, I'd be happy if you could help me solving my wrong design layout pattern too.

**MyFrame.java**

```
package ms0.gui;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame () {
        setTitle("This is an example title");
        setSize(600,600);
        setLocation(750,640);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    
        
        
        //Main Container
        Container mainContainer = this.getContentPane();
        mainContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,6));
        mainContainer.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.green));
        
        
        //JButton Positions
        JButton topButton = new JButton("Oben");
        JButton bottomButton = new JButton("Unten");
        JButton leftButton = new JButton("Links");
        JButton rightButton = new JButton("Rechts");

        
        //Panel Top
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5));
        topPanel.add(topButton);
        mainContainer.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        //Panel Middle
        
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        middlePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));
        middlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(4,4,4));
        middlePanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        
        
        //Grid Panel Right
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(4,4,4));
        rightPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        rightPanel.add(rightButton);
        
        
        //Grid Panel Left
        
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1,5,5));
        gridPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 3));
        gridPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        gridPanel.add(leftButton);
        
        
        
        //Center Box
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Center Box", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,3));
        
        middlePanel.add(gridPanel);
        mainContainer.add(label);
        mainContainer.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainContainer.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        
        //Panel Bottom
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(3));
        bottomPanel.add(bottomButton);
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        bottomPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 3));
        mainContainer.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
    //Siegel
    
        
        
            String filepath = "/resources/siegel.jpg";      
            int picWidth = 150;
            int picHeight = 150;
            
            ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filepath));
            //Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(picWidth, picHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
            
            mainContainer.add(new JButton(image1));
    
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as a very basic example, nothing but `BorderLayout`

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        setTitle("This is an example title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JButton("Top button (stretched)"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JButton("Left button (stretched)"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(new JButton("Right button (stretched)"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(new JButton("Bottom button (stretched)"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Picture");
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));

        add(label);
    }
}
```

Remember, simple is often best.

Now, if you absolutely, positively must have the label/picture in another container, you can simply make use of `GridBagLayout`, as it will centre the child component(s) by default, for example...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Picture");
label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));

// Automatic center position
JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
mainPane.add(label);

add(mainPane);
```

And you don't have to use `EmptyBorder`.  `GridBagLayout` will allow to supply `insets` which will do the same thing

Comment: Worked perfect! But how can I embed now a custom size image from my resource folder inside the main container ? I want to create methods for the buttons so I can change the direction of the displayed image regarding the clicked button

Comment: That depends.  `JLabel` can display images - so you could just use it, or you need to derive a custom component and paint the image yourself through custom painting